is it possible to multiply a raylib vector2 with int?
I want to do something like:
from pyray import Vector2  
v2 = Vector2(1,2)
print(v2 * 10)

But I get:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *:
'_cffi_backend.__CDataOwn' and 'int'

Same result if I multiple the vector with a float.
Is there a way to do this operation in raylib? I know I can do
v2 = Vector2(1,2)
print(v2.x * 10)
print(v2.y * 10)

but it's a bit annoying to write 2 lines instead of 1.

where is this pyray package installed from ?

from pypi via pip

pip install pyray
Requirement already satisfied: pyray in ./anaconda/lib/python3.12/site-packages (0.1.0)
$ python
Python 3.12.2 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Feb 16 2024, 20:50:58) [GCC 12.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.



from pyray import Vector2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: cannot import name 'Vector2' from 'pyray' (/home/tester/anaconda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyray/init.py)




specify exactly which package you installed from pypi. i installed raylib-py .  v2=raylibpy.Vector2(1,2)



print(v2 * 10 )
(10.0, 20.0)



